# Can't create TCP/IP socket (10106) when trying to connect with spatie / laravel-backup

Tags: mysql, backup, laravel-7, dump, laravel-permission

I'm using `spatie/laravel-backup` package in my **laravel project**

When I want to backup via command line everything works fine via command

```
php artisan backup:run
```

or

```
php artisan backup:run --only-db
```

or

```
php artisan backup:run --only-files
```

But when I execute the command from the controller by `artisan::call('backup:run')`, I have the following error:

> **Exception message: The dump process failed with exitcode 2 : Misuse of shell builtins : mysqldump: Got error: 2004: Can't create TCP/IP
> socket (10106) when trying to connect**

***note: this error not shown with php artisan backup:run --only-files command***

please any help!!